# UWP Hosted App (Javascript) - authentication

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, hosted-app

according to my research, UWP-hosted apps should be able to use the **current user** to authenticate at webservices / webpages, if the following is true:

Capabilities:

- **Enterprise Authentication**
- Private Network (Client&Server)
- Internet Client

However - I experience the following:

- If I disable anonymous authentication on the webpage:

  - The Hosted-App tries to load the page, gets a 401 (with "WWW-Authentication: Negotiate and WWW-Authentication: NTLM) and then.....just sits there and does **nothing** (no login dialog, no error, just displays the splash-screen)
- If I enable anonymous authentication, but [Authorize] my controllers:

  - The initial page loads OK (of course...there is no authentication)
  - The first calls to a webservice will show the login-dialogue, subsequent calls are OK.

So - my questions:

- is what I want (automatically use the current logged in user for authentication) even possible?
- If yes - what could be my problem?

Thanks in advance

Johannes Colmsee

Update:

It seems that (all observations I made in the last hour - the following are all "from remote PC connect to host PC"):

- my Kerberos settings were fucked up (if you install Forefront - it will setup all so that *it* works, but *nothing else*....
- After fixing that - I can connect to the page with "regular browsers"
- However - if I try it from the UWP-App, this happens:

  - if I use the IP-Adresse - after the first "401" response of the server....nothing
  - if I use the "Hostname" (not the FQDN) - communicates 3 times with server (3x 401) - after this point a dialoge *should* show up, but it does not.
  - Unfortunately I cannot use FQDN (some name resolving problem idk...)

Both - IP-Adresse and Hostname work fine in "regular browsers".
I cannot try out HTTPS right now (browsers I can shut up about certificate problems, UWP-hosted I can't)

Now....some observations from "local-to-local" connection:

- Hostname: current user is picked up automatically
- localhost: same
- IP-Adresse: sits at splash screen

In this scenario I cannot watch the network-traffic (no fiddler or other means).

More Infos tomorrow maybe.

Comment: Can your current  user login successfully?

Comment: When I enter my current user in the login-dialog that pops up when I do WebAPI calls - yes. The problem is, that it is not "automatically used"

Comment: Your mean that you need to typing user name password each time right?

Comment: The first time I do call WebAPI Controller. Subsequent calls will use that user.

Comment: If I do "disable anonymouse" authentication", there is no login dialogue, the app simply "gives up" after the 401 response it gets (which seems to be "OK"....the WWW-Authenticate headers sent from IIS seem to be OK) (gives up at loading index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have some more Information on this Problem - it might help others to fix their Problems - so, I add it as an extra entry instead of updating.

After some Investigation - I found out, that also Edge has problems loading the pages.

this thread has some Information to Workaround / fix the issue:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/0face535-3c7a-4658-be34-6c376322ca34/microsoft-edge-cant-open-local-domains?forum=win10itpronetworking

for me - what worked was putting the page into "trusted sites" list - after that - Edge did load the page.

About the "automatically use current user" thingy - again - test it with Edge - if Edge does not use it, neither your app will.

For me - Opening the page with "just the Computer Name" (vs. FQDN) did use the "current user" for both - Edge and UWP-App.

Maybe one could configure it in a way that FQDN would also use the "current user" automatically.

More Information might follow.